# Meaning of トッツケ on a house plan

Tags: meaning, katakana, dialects

Same as with my question about a Kanji I tried to identify on a bad image source, I have a katakana word I need to understand / translate.

The word reads トッツケ, as marked in this image:
[image: house map]

I tried to find out what it means, and I am thinking it might be some kind of 'foreroom' a room you go through before entering the actual house?
I might be totally wrong though, so I would be very happy about any input.

again, thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

取っ付**き** (or 取り付き) means "starter", "first (step/impression)", "clue" etc.

大辞林 defines [取っ付き](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/j_dictionary/ITEM-DJR_toxtutuki_-010/) like this:

> とっつき【取っ付き】
>   ①物事のやり始め。初手。 「－から失敗する」
>   ②初めて会った時に受ける感じ。第一印象。 「－の悪い男だ」
>   ③**ある建物・場所などに入る時，一番初めに通る所。**一番手前。入り口。**「－の部屋」**「正門を這入ると，－の大通りの左右に植ゑてある銀杏の並木が眼に付いた／三四郎 漱石」

(FWIW, the third definition seems to be common in middle Japan, but I personally did not know this.)

So at least トッツキの部屋 means "the first/front room", "entrance", etc.

I could find no exact example of 取っ付**け**の部屋. But I think 取っ付け should mean the same thing, because 付く and 付ける are semantically the same except that the latter is transitive.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the late reply. And yes, that makes sense. It was where I was coming from too, I just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook a different explanation for the word.